# Remove a pattern using sed which has square brackets and quotes

Tags: regex, shell, sed

How to remove a line which has this pattern using sed

```
resourceNames: [""]
```

I tried

```
sed -i '/resourceNames: [""]/d' ./sa.yaml
```

A part of file looks like this

```
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: [""]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
```

Comment: if  any line containing `resourceNames` has to be deleted, `sed -i '/resourceNames:/d'` would do.. not necessary to match entire line.. if not, sample could have added lines with `resourceNames` to be retained as well as deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright.I found the issue in my code. This worked

```
 sed -i '/  resourceNames: [[]""[]]/d' ./sa.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

A better and more robust regex for your `sed` command:

```
sed -i '/\s*resourceNames:\s*\[""\]/d' ./sa.yaml
```

where you just escape the `[]` to avoid them being interpreted as character range, character list also, instead of space it is better to use `\s*`